# Fast attachments with markdown

Tags: notepad++, markdown, multimarkdown

I have a document like this:

```
A lot of text. 
insert:good graph:x
More text. insert: :y

Even more text. 

insert:another figure:z
```

I want to change all `insert:description:x` to `![description][A_Standardized_filepath/x.pdf]` because that command `![][]` will attach a file into my markdown-document. Note that x is the variable I'm changing, and the description is unique for each variable. The file path, however, is always the same. (Note that `y` had no description, which I solved by adding a space.)

This would allow me to speed up the process of creating documents.

---

I'm on Windows 7; I prefer to use Notepad++ for writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know notepad++, but if it has find and replace using regular expressions then you should be able to adapt this. In vim, I would use:

```
:%s/insert:\([^:]*\):\([^ :]*\)/![\1][A_Standardized_filepath\/\2.pdf]/g
```

The `%` means 'act on every line'; the `s` starts the `substitute` command (`s/change this/to this/`), and the `g` on the end means 'act on every match on a line' (as opposed to just the first match, which is vim's default behaviour).

The meat of it is in the first part. the `\(\)` indicate capture groups; since notepad++ is relatively new, I expect you won't need the backslashes there. Everything between the first set of `\(\)` is referred to as `\1` on the right-hand side of the command (again, this may be different in notepad++: perl uses `$1` instead, for example), everything between the second set of `\(\)` is referred to as `\2` on the right-hand side, etc.

`[^:]` means 'any character except for `:`', while `[^ :]` means 'any character except for space or `:`'. This assumes that you'll never have spaces in the filename part of your construction.

If someone with knowledge of notepad++ comes along, they should feel free to cannibalise this regex into an answer.